A generalization of integration by parts
Many years ago, I came up with a short generalization of integration by parts that was definitely known, but I could never find a reference for it. I was considering throwing it on arxiv, but before I do, is anyone aware of it?
For $k$ a positive integer, let $f^{(k)}(x)$ denote the $k$th derivative and $f^{(-k)}$ denote a choice of $k$th antiderivative.
By iterating the product rule, we see that for positive $k$:
$$(fg)^{(k)}=\sum\limits_{r\ge 0} \binom{k}{r} f^{(k-r)}g^{(r)}$$.
(Since $k$ is positive, $\binom{k}{r}=0$ when $r>k$)
The generalization is simply that this holds for negative $k$ as well, under certain conditions that allow the sum to converge nicely. For example, for $k=-1$, this gives the ``tabular" method of integration by parts:
$$(fg)^{(-1)}=\sum\limits_{r\ge 0} (-1)^r f^{(-1-r)}g^{(r)}$$
One can obtain a short proof of the generalization by comparing this to multiplying a certain formal power series expansion of $(x+y)^{-k}$ by
$(x+y)^k$.
An easy set of conditions where this applies is when $g(x)$ is a polynomial. A more non-trivial set of conditions where the above formula seems to hold is when $g(x)$ is analytic for some $|x-a|<r$, the effective supremum of $f$ is bounded on this interval (or on all finite intervals if $r=\infty$), and we choose our anti-derivatives such that
$f^{(-k)}(x)=\int\limits_a^x f^{(-k+1)}(s)ds$
